# Filter not applying on dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

My filter for `weight_class` wont apply, I've tried filtering specifically for `weight_class==10924` and then converting dtype for 'weight_class', I've also stripped the columns but still get both Rice products with weight class not filtered

```
# Fill missing values with zeros in the original DataFrame
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

df['weight_class'] = df['weight_class'].astype(int)

# Define the grocery basket
grocery_basket = ['Loaf of white bread', 'Sunflower oil', 'Maize meal', 'White sugar', 'Full cream milk - fresh', 'Rice', 'Cake flour', 'Bar Of Bath Soap', 'Spaghetti', 'Peanut butter', 'Cereals', 'Rooibos tea']

# Filter the DataFrame
selected_items = df[(df['product'].isin(grocery_basket)) | ((df['product'] == 'Rice') & (df['weight_class'] != 10917))]

# Print the selected items
print(selected_items)
```

Here's an extract of the result:

`prod_id                  product  weight_class  Dec-20  Jan-21  Feb-21  \ 68   12131006         Bar Of Bath Soap         10851   12.22   11.92   12.24    74    1212002              Rooibos tea         10855   46.83   46.87   46.78    89    1152003            Peanut butter         10884   32.84   33.32   33.64    96    1113001                Spaghetti         10895   15.85   16.47   16.60    99    1116005                  Cereals         10895   41.45   42.28   39.33    108   1112001      Loaf of white bread         10902   15.21   15.63   15.81    117   1111001                     Rice         10917   28.14   29.89   30.06    132   1111001                     Rice         10924   39.42   42.28   43.41    136   1116001               Cake flour         10926   29.37   29.12   29.17    138   1116003               Maize meal         10926    0.00    0.00    0.00    141   1181001              White sugar         10926   44.74   43.49   45.31    142   1116003               Maize meal         10931    0.00    0.00    0.00    152   1141001  Full cream milk - fresh         10963   28.90   28.79   29.27`

Expecting the result to display the `selected_items` with one Rice having a `weight_class` of 10924

Comment: Is there another product with the `weight_class` to 10917 ?

Comment: yes there's about 13 other products with weight class 10917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['product'].isin(grocery_basket)` selects `Rice` independently of the other condition since you're using an OR (`|`).

You can select the products from the grocery_basket only if they are not Rice or not weight_class 10917:

```
df[  (df['product'].isin(grocery_basket))
   & ((df['product'] != 'Rice') | (df['weight_class'] != 10917))]
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
df[  (df['product'].isin(grocery_basket))
   & ~((df['product'] == 'Rice') & (df['weight_class'] == 10917))]
```

Comment: Thank you, just for understanding, my mistake was using | between the filters?

Comment: @Kyle yes, and the second part of the condition was also incorrect you needed `df['product'] != 'Rice'` and an OR (`|`) instead of AND (`&`).

Answer (score 0):

If there is no other product with `weight_class` equal to 10917, you can filter it.

```py
selected_items = df.loc[(df['product'].isin(grocery_basket)) & (df['weight_class'] != 10917)]
```

Otherwise, you can drop duplicates based on `product` column:

```py
selected_items = df.loc[df['product'].isin(grocery_basket)]
# Sort items before drop duplicates
sort_items = selected_items.sort_values(by=['product', 'weight_class'])
# Drop duplicates (in case you want to keep the higher weight_class)
final_items = sort_items.drop_duplicates(subset=['product'], keep='last')
```

Comment: this would've been a better alternative to my code, thank you